# PHP MYSQL Next and Previous Product Buttons

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a dynamic page that pulls the categories from the database. this page is `categories.php?CTGID=####`, `CTGID` standing for the category number. Each product then has an ID assigned to it.

When they click on the product within the category it goes to a page `Products.php?ID=###`. What I want to create is when they are within the Product page there is a next and previous button.

What I would essentially need it to do is get the `CTGID` of the current product ID then the next button would be the ID of the next product withing that Category ID.

```
<?php
$db=mysql_connect ("localhost",[username],[password]) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("rentals");
$rentID = $_GET['ID'];
//Strip html
$strip_ID = strip_tags($rentID);
$html = htmlentities($strip_ID, ENT_QUOTES);
$escape = addslashes($html);
$table="online_rental_db";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID=$escape";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rentals = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$description = ucwords(strtolower($rentals['Description']));
$image = $rentals['Image'];
$download = $rentals['PDF'];
$ID = $rentals['ID'];
$CTGID = $rentals['CTGID'];
$category = $rentals['Category'];
$video = $rentals['Video'];
$bytes = filesize("rentals/".$download);
$model = $rentals['Model'];
$made = ucwords(strtolower($rentals['Manufacturer']));
$productnum = $rentals['Productnum'];
```

then on the page I just echo out what I need in what area. I have read some articles on the next and previous buttons, but decided I might need some extra advice!

Comment: Protip: don't include your database's username & password when posting them on the internet. I went ahead and removed them for you.

Comment: `addslashes()` is to SQL injection defense as a piece of toilet paper is to soaking up an ocean. DON'T USE IT.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you've tried, but in the past I've implemented getting next/previous values from the DB with the following queries:

```
$curId  = 42;  // current product id
$curCat = 1;   // current category

$sqlPrev = 'SELECT `id` FROM `table`
            WHERE `id` < '$curId' AND `catId` = '$curCat'
            ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;

$sqlNext = 'SELECT `id` FROM `table`
            WHERE `id` > '$curId' AND `catId` = '$curCat'
            ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1;

// execute each query
```

If you get no result back from one of the two queries, it means you are on the first or last item in that category so there is no prev/next button in that case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I will try this out! How would you go about adding the Next And Previous Links? Would it just be <a href="products.php?ID=$sqlNext

Comment: Each of those queries would return 1 result with the `id` of the next/previous item, so presumably you just echo a link like `yoursite.com/product.php?id=$id_from_query_result&cat=$curCat`

Comment: You have to execute `$sqlNext` and take the result from it and then use that in your url.

Comment: By the way, instead of using `addslashes` to escape your input parameter, use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) instead since you are using the old (deprecated) `mysql_*` functions.  In the future, look into `Mysqli` or `PDO_MySQL` for connecting to the DB